# Invoke a wine installed application from command line

Tags: command-line, wine

I have installed **DivX** player using **wine** in my ubuntu. I would like to invoke the player from terminal. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are using wine installed from the repositories then wine related files is stored in a folder called `~/.wine`

Windows programs are stored within this folder - for example `~/.wine/drive_c/program_files/Internet Explorer`

You can start a windows program in a similar way as from a command line in windows but prefix it with `wine`

for example

```
wine "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Thus if your divx called (for example) `divxplayer.exe` is installed - for example in `~/.wine/drive_c/program files/divx`

then you can start your wine divx player

```
wine "c:\program files\divx\divxplayer.exe"
```

Comment: logically it would be `wine "c:\program\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"` - drive_c/Program is an unusual path though - I presume you created that manually

Comment: Apologies for the previous comment. I was going to ask a question about how to deal with (x86) in the file path. I didn't know how to deal with the brackets n the command line using quotations. I think that i meant to not post the comment that i did. I have since deleted it. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: `wine explorer` is useful to find where your binaries

Comment: I installed with `sudo apt install wine` and my wine ended up in `usr/bin/` from where I can launch a windows program using `./wine <program_name>`.  Is there any ways to get it in the home folder like you describe because cd'ing each time is a pain.

Comment: Is there any possibility to make use of some sort of `PATH`? Something like `wine launch MyProgram` without the long path, full of spaces?