# How do I start a wine program from the command line?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invoke a wine installed application from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65487/invoke-a-wine-installed-application-from-command-line)

I would like to start a wine program via the terminal so if something goes wrong I can see what.

What command should I type in to get the program started?

for an example lets say Spotify.

Comment: ok, it's a dupe. But why downvote it?

Comment: not me... but dont worry about it... we all get random downvotes from time-to-time...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to

```
wine /path/to/your/exe/program.exe
```

Comment: `$ wine Spotify.exe
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Spotify.exe"`
sorry it doesn't work...

Comment: @Alvar I assume `wine Spotify.exe` will default to the `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/` folder. Your programs might be installed either in `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files[ x86]/Spotify/Spotify.exe` or `~/.wine/drive_c/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe` so you should write out the whole path, e.g `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe`