# Running EXE files with WINE through terminal

Tags: wine

I have WINE installed and I have figured out how to use it to run Windows programs from their installed directories in Windows from Linux in my dual-boot configuration. I now want to keep these programs in my application panel. So, what would the command be to run something with WINE?

Comment: Does it show up on your panel now? Right click it and choose to lock it to the panel, does that work? I don't have Linux booted right now and don't run WINE often sorry if that's off the mark. There is this question that might help [Invoke a WINE-installed application from the command line] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/65487/invoke-a-wine-installed-application-from-command-line)

Comment: It does not work with games launched this way.

Comment: Bummer well it's a good question and deserves a good answer!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I actually found it! `wine (filepath)`

Comment: That's what the link I provided above says :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out right after posting the question. I figured I'd leave this up just in case some other poor soul in my situation needs help :)

Comment: Yeah good idea and you know you can accept your own answer, right? You dont get any rep for that but its totally acceptable :) Raju's looks good too, whatrver solves your problem

Answer (score 5):

make sure that the program has 'executable' permission

```
chmod +x game.exe
```

You can create short cut files(desktop files with your desired image as icon) using the steps mentioned below link
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Above link even explains, how you can add your programs to launcher panel

Comment: I know :) There is a program called alacarte that allows you to easily do that in GNOME and Unity